# Unable to Filter Items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

So, I'm trying to create a filter for this list of stores, so only the ones with content that is equal to the value of the input box will display. Unfortunately, my filter does not work correctly. For one, whatever I type in the input box causes all of my store elements to add the 'display' class, which causes my items to receive the style 'display: none;'. Secondly, it's not updating every time a key is pressed.

HTML:

```
                 <li class="p-3 clearfix store display">

                        <div class='float-left w-50'>

                            <div class='mb-1'><strong>Store Number:</strong><span class="store-info">

                                <?php

                                if (strlen($row['store_num']) < 4) {

                                    if (strlen($row['store_num']) == 3) {
                                        echo '0' . $row['store_num'];
                                    } else if (strlen($row['store_num']) == 2) {
                                        echo '00' . $row['store_num'];
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    echo $row['store_num'];
                                }

                                ?>

                            </span></div>

                            <div class='mb-1'><strong>Store Name:&nbsp;</strong><span class='store-info'><?php echo $row['store_name']; ?></span></div>

                            <div class='clearfix mb-1'>


                                    <p class='float-left'><strong>Address:&nbsp;</strong></p>


                                    <span class='d-block store-info float-left'><?php echo $row['store_street']; ?></span>
                                    <br>
                                  <span class='d-block store-info float-left'><?php echo $row['store_city']; ?>,&nbsp;<?php echo strtoupper($row['store_state']); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['store_zip']; ?></span>


                            </div> <!-- mb-1 -->

                        </div> <!-- float-left -->

                        <div class="float-left w-50 clearfix">

                            <div class="d-inline float-right">

                                <div class='mb-1'>
                                    <strong>Time Zone:&nbsp;</strong><span class='time-zone store-info'><?php echo strtoupper($row['time_zone']); ?></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class='mb-1'>
                                    <strong>Current Time:&nbsp;</strong><time>3:45pm</time>
                                </div>

                                <div class='mb-1'>
                                    <strong>Phone Number:</strong><span class='store-info'>

                                    <?php

                                        $phone = $row['store_phone'];

                                        $area = substr($phone, 0, 3);
                                        $prefix = substr($phone, 4, 3);
                                        $line = substr($phone, 6, 4);

                                        echo '(' . $area . ') ' . $prefix . '-' . $line;

                                     ?>

                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class='mb-1'>
                                    <strong>Fax Number:</strong><span class='store-info'>

                                    <?php

                                        $phone = $row['store_fax'];

                                        $area = substr($phone, 0, 3);
                                        $prefix = substr($phone, 4, 3);
                                        $line = substr($phone, 6, 4);

                                        echo '(' . $area . ') ' . $prefix . '-' . $line;

                                     ?>

                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </div> <!-- d-inline -->

                        </div> <!-- float-right -->

                    </li> <!-- clearfix -->
```

JavaScript:

```
var search = document.getElementById('search');
var stores = document.querySelectorAll('.store');

search.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {

    var data = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    stores.forEach(function(store) {

        var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.store-info');

        for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            if (spans[i].innerText.toLowerCase() != data) {
                store.classList.remove('display');
            } else {
                store.classList.add('display');
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: `display: none` is not a class. Is this a side effect from your `display` class?

Comment: I understand this, but I have a class called 'display' that just has the style display: none. Sorry if this was confusing. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could make the following changes to your javascript to resolve the issues you're facing. Please see comments in code for explaination of what's going on:

```
search.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {

    var query = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    if (search.value.length >= 0) {
        search.classList.add('focused');
        label.classList.add('focused');
    } else {
        search.classList.remove('focused');
        label.classList.remove('focused');
    }

  // recommend performing this query in the keyup event to ensure
  // that you're working with the most up to date state of the DOM
  var stores = document.querySelectorAll(".store");

  stores.forEach(function(store) {

    // query .store-info from current store
    var spans = store.querySelectorAll(".store-info");

    // hide the store by default
    store.style.display = 'none';

    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {

      var storeInfoText = spans[i].innerText.toLowerCase();

      // consider revising search logic like so
      if (storeInfoText.indexOf(query) !== -1 || !query) {

        // display the store if some match was found
        store.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }

    });

});
```

Link to [working jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6wb1nLus/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. It's not causing all elements to remove the display class, but it's not filtering correctly.

Comment: .display {
display: none;
}

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had it originally to display: block but changed it to display: none prior to posting.

Comment: Hm, still not working. Essentially, whatever I type is bringing up all of the stores, and then not updating the list when I delete the value. For example, if I type in '80', which only one store of the three I'm testing with has that store number, all three populate and display. If I delete the input out to nothing, all of them continue to show.

Comment: I checked and unfortunately there are none.

Comment: Nope, same thing, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you think it could be searching for any instances of the string of characters in whatever order? Now when I type a '+' sign all disappear, but when I type anything at all, for instance, drive, not all stores have drive in it, just a couple, but they all have an instance of at least one letter

Comment: Can you take a copy of the html that is rendered into your browser and upload it to jsFiddle so that I can take a closer look?

Comment: Yeah sure, one moment.

Comment: Okay that came down to a single character! Please see updated answer `store.style.display = 'none'` should not have `;` in it. I've also included a working jsFiddle - hope this helps!

Comment: Oh god lol. I can't believe we both overlooked that! Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

```
I think your issue with it showing everything is because of the add remove... if a store already has display it will re add it and then only remove it once where as if it doesn’t you will get an error so try toggle
```

var search = document.getElementById('search');
    var stores = document.querySelectorAll('.store');

```
 search.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {

var data = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

stores.forEach(function(store) {

    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.store-info');

     spans.filter(span=>{
      if(span.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(data)){
       store.classList.toggle('display');


     }else{store.classList.toggle('display')

       })

   });
```